# How to capture closure compiler output in PowerShell?

Tags: javascript, powershell, google-closure-compiler

I am typing this at the PowerShell command line:

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar --js temp1.js --js_output_file temp2.js
```

and it generates this error output:

```
temp1.js:359: WARNING - Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used.
$acms.x
^

0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

(I know exactly what's wrong with the JavaScript: that's not the issue here.)

I want to capture this error output. However, if I try:

```
$errs = java -jar closure-compiler.jar --js temp1.js --js_output_file temp2.js
```

$errs ends up empty. But then if I try:

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar --js temp1.js --js_output_file temp2.js 2>errs.txt
```

errs.txt captures this:

```
java.exe : temp1.js:359: WARNING - Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used.
At line:1 char:5
+ java <<<<  -jar closure-compiler.jar --js temp1.js --js_output_file temp2.js 2>errs.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (temp1.js:359: W...not being used.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

$acms.x
^



0
 error(s), 
1
 warning(s)
```

Clearly the error output from the closure compiler is getting interleaved with PowerShell error output.

Is there any way to just capture the closure compiler output?

Comment: What was wrong with the javascript? I'm seeing that error and don't know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124442/what-does-warning-suspicious-code-the-result-of-the-getprop-operator-is-no

Comment: The offending line was just "$acms.x". It was legal JavaScript, but the compiler was telling me that the property 'x' wasn't being used.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful. I'll take a closer look at my typedef declarations and how / if they are being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing:

```
$errs = command 2>&1
```

`$errs.Exception` will give you the message.

If only the error ( and only one) occured, $errs will have an `ErrorRecord` and you will be able to do the above and get the error that you want.

Otherwise, it will be an array of errorrecords and / or normal output.

So you will have to do

`$errs | ?{$_.GetType().Name -eq "ErrorRecord"} | select -expand exception`

Comment: It was the second of the two. Thanks.