# What does "WARNING - Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used." mean?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

> "WARNING - Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used."

I'm seeing this for two lines in my JavaScript code when I use the closure compiler. They are typedefs in among other typedefs that don't report issues. What should I be looking for?

**EDIT**

Affected code:

```
/**
 * @typedef {{playerId: number, playerName: string, baseScores: Array.<number>, bonusScores: Array.<number>,
 *          teamScoreAdjustments: Array.<number>}}
 */
wias.GameTableTeamMember;

/**
 * @typedef {{id: number, teamMembers: Array<wias.GameTableTeamMember>, teamName: string}}
 */
wias.GameTableTeam;

/**
 * @typedef {{id: number, availableRound: boolean, bonusScoring: boolean, complete: boolean, gameLength: number,
 *          gameType: string, lastPlayed: string, numberOfRounds: number, teams: Array.<wias.GameTableTeam>, winners:
 *          Array.<string>}}
 */
wias.GameTable;
```

Warning:

```
wias.js:77: WARNING - Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used.
wias.GameTableTeam;
^
```

Why a warning there and not elsewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what the warning means, but I'm curious to see the actual code it is talking about...

Answer (score 6):

It means that you have code which does nothing.

Typedef's (or record types) are more tricky for the compiler to point to the exact spot where the issue is, but somewhere you are getting a value which is not being used.

some reading about the type system and what works best with the compiler
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Uq_vNyPZjlRvYZJclX6N37Fjsiah4XNciEPSBfFiREs/edit

and to recreate the warning simply

```
if (true) {
   //have nothing in here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that link and the answer. Still confused about why that particular line of code is singled out. All typedef declarations look like no-ops in closure compiler, yet only one is singled out here.

Comment: I think it is because it finds it difficult to track down typedefs in relation to classes and also typedefs are treated more loosely. By Changing a typedef to a class i have managed to track a few warnings with more clarity.

Comment: i just woke. getProp is a closure way of saying the internal getter. So what it is saying is that wias.GameTableTeam; is never used in your app.

Comment: Here's the thing, wias.GameTableTeam is used immediately in the definition of wias.GameTable, which does not issue a warning. Am I actually not allowed to nest typedefs?

Comment: you are allowed to nest typedefs, but as per that article I linked too originally typedefs are loose and fast and do not promise/assure that something is being used vs classes. The compiler cannot ascertain for certain that the type declared on the typedef is used.